# FORTRAN error - undefined reference to 'jfix'

Tags: fortran

I am newbie to FORTRAN. I have some FORTRAN programs written in Intel FORTRAN and now I am compiling them using gfortran.

One of the subroutines uses the JFIX() function. When I complie the following error is thrown.

```
undefined reference to 'jfix_'
```

The subroutine has reference to this intrinsic function on the top like `External::JFIX`

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: Just a minor point, intrinsic functions don't need an `external :: jfix` (for example) declaration. The `external` statement is used to refer to routines which are defined outside of a program or module. Often it is used to refer to a routine contained in a library. So, my guess is (as mentioned in the answers), that `JFIX` is part of an extension library written by Intel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFIX is an Intel extension to FORTRAN.  It converts its argument to INTEGER(4).

There may be a GNU FORTRAN equivalent, or you may have to provide it yourself.

The Intel FORTRAN Language Reference is available from various places on the web.  Here's [one](http://qcd.phys.cmu.edu/QCDcluster/intel/for_lang.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I found the equivalent function for JFIX(), in my case I had to use INT(A).

Answer (score 0):

JFIX may be the one you need, but you should be careful as JFIX not only converts real to integers (as INT does), but also all other kinds of stuff to integer(4).

From the Intel Fortran Language Reference found [here](http://qcd.phys.cmu.edu/QCDcluster/intel/for_lang.pdf), it converts

INTEGER(1), INTEGER(2), INTEGER(4), INTEGER(8), 
REAL(4), REAL(8), REAL(16), COMPLEX(4), 
COMPLEX(8), COMPLEX(16)

to

INTEGER(4)

That was just to say to you and future readers: while it's the equivalent of INT in your case here, it is not the case everywhere.

As you're new to Fortran let me just give one more precision: the number between parenthesis is the precision kind of the variable. For instance, REAL(4) is simple precision on a "conventional" architecture, REAL(8) double precision.